# Firefox - Link to external SSO website does not trigger redirect

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, firefox, single-sign-on

I'm building a react app with the route `/login` to be redirect to an external SSO site.
The login flow is as following:

- When the user clicks the `a` tag with href on the frontend page /login, the browser will redirect to a backend page /api/login.
- The backend will then build a login URL for the SSO External Site, populating the client secret and passing a state parameter to the frontend URL that will be used for redirection after login
- The backend will redirect the page to the SSO URL, where the user will perform the login on SSO.
- After a successful login on SSO, the SSO site will redirect to another backend URL `/api/login/callback` with an authorization code.
- The backend will call the SSO API to grant access and refresh tokens, and then redirect to the frontend URL passed earlier in the state parameter, with URL params containing the token info.
- The frontend will read the token from the params and store it in local storage.

the process works perfectly fine on Chrome, Edge and Safari but in Firefox, the redirection won't be triggered, instead it fires up a refresh action to refresh the `/login` page only.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue?

Expecting the redirection to be processed correctly on Firefox.

Comment: I've also tried to set `target="_blank"` to the `a` tag and in the new tab it's working fine as expected. But what if i wish to keep the user to be in the same tab?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.